# Instances Aren't Behaving Independently with Proximity 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes, shape-keys, instances

Alright, I have checked about for similar questions but I've done something quite niche with my mesh to try and replicate shape keys within geometry nodes so I think this might be a special case that I need help with. My problem is that my meshes are rising to meet a target with a proximity node except when they rise I also want them to activate my shape key alternative so the fishes mouth closes. As the fish rises up its mouth does close but this makes all the instances of the fish's mouth close instead of the one close to the target which is not the desired result. I'll send a picture of my node set up and the attributes colour 1 and 2 are effectively shape keys which can be switched between using the factor input attached to the map range.

[image: Node Set Up][image: Current Result]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, *Shape Keys* cannot be processed in *Geometry Nodes*. However, you can mix shapes by wrapping the shapes into individual objects and processing them in your *Geometry Nodes*. For example like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274364/145249

Comment: I've already completed that step, so now I have a factor scale that switches between the two meshes within geometry nodes but my trouble is that I'm struggling to have it's effects be individual to each instance if you see what I mean? So one fish is close to the cube but all the fishes mouths are closed. :(

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean (your screenshot is so small that I didn't look closely there). In this case you would have to structure it quite differently, because contrary to your assumption, here you always instantiate only one object, so they all look the same. More information on this topic can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters. Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ so that I can have a closer look and don't have to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, in this case, you would just have to align the individual objects correctly first and apply the transformations.

Then you can instantiate these objects and process them correctly.

[image]

In your example, this is a very individual use case with relatively little benefit for other visitors (also because Blender 3.0 is now considered obsolete), so please forgive me for not explaining it all in detail now.

But the basic principle is that you apply all position changes after instantiation instead of before.

You can also save on the `Geometry Proximity` node, and use the reference to the object you are using to control it as a function of the position of the points where you instantiate the fish.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.0+)*</sub>