# Objects moving away on Z axis

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I want to separately distance the square frames on Z axis by nearing the green sphere. These are mirrored on z axis, multiplied in the same collection, no array. I've found [similar effects here](https://youtu.be/k5HhYzd1LjM)

Should I just put them as instances on circled grid or is there an option with just setting a position in geometry nodes?
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE! This answer might help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283189/145249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Should I just put them as instances on circle or is there an option with just setting a position in geometry nodes?"*

- Yes, in this case it makes sense to instantiate the objects as instances along the points of a circle.
- Yes, of course, with *Geometry Nodes* you can wonderfully change the position of instances according to your wishes.

[image]

On the one hand, you simply instantiate your objects at the points of the circle in the best case, and on the other hand, you simply move the instantiated objects along their Z-axis as soon as the sphere (or whatever) is in a certain proximity to their position.

[image]

If you want to solve the whole task with Geometry Nodes (which I assume) then the sphere is positioned somewhere on the circle via the *Curve Factor*. This *Curve Factor* is in this case also the value you would have to animate.

The *Curve Factor* is somewhere in the range between $0$ and $1$, and in this example I just use the current frame for a repeating sequence.

Then you only need the distance between the position of the sphere and each instance (`Geometry Proximity` is not needed here).

To customize the range, you simply use the `Map Range` node, and use the resulting value to move the corresponding instances on the Z-axis with `Translate Instances` as the sphere approaches in the defined range.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: great response, as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome sklttn, I hope it's what you looking for, in this case I used a point that move like the sphere to do the effect because as the sphere has a volume it mess it up a bit the effect with `Geometry Proximity`. Also I let the Frames as instances.

[image]
[image]

[image]
Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, thats very close to what I've been trying to make. I was hoping for hints, not for the complete project. Thank you very much!